# CMake : /usr/include not used to find fftw3.h

Tags: c++, c, cmake, cross-compiling, fftw

I'm working on a personal project to cross compile for a Raspberry Pi with CMake. This is the first time I build a project with it.

One of the file I compile include the `fftw3.h` header. This file is present in the `/usr/include` folder as shown by the following output :

```
$ ls /usr/include/fftw3*
/usr/include/fftw3.f
/usr/include/fftw3.f03
/usr/include/fftw3.h 
/usr/include/fftw3l.f03
/usr/include/fftw3q.f03
```

The file is successfully found by cmake with `find_path(FFTW_FOLDER NAMES fftw3.h)` and even if cmake looks in this path by default, I add it explicitly when constructing my target with `target_include_directories(${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC /usr/include)`.

However, when comes the compilation, I have the classic error message telling me that `fftw3.h` is not found.

If I copy the file and put it in my home folder and add my home folder in the include list there is no problem and the compilation works.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks,
Damien

**Edit 1 to answer @Pablo and @hikerjobs**:

This is how my compile line looks like:

```
/home/littlemonster/projects/rpi-workspace/rpi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-
linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++   
-Dmatrix_hal_EXPORTS -I/home/littlemonster/projects/rpi-
workspace/lib/matrix-hal/matrix-creator-hal  -fPIC   -Wall -Werror -
Wextra -Wdouble-promotion -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/matrix-
hal.dir/matrix-creator-hal/cpp/driver/cross_correlation.cpp.o -c 
/home/littlemonster/projects/rpi-workspace/lib/matrix-hal/matrix-
creator-hal/cpp/driver/cross_correlation.cpp

In file included from /home/littlemonster/projects/rpi-
workspace/lib/matrix-hal/matrix-creator-
hal/cpp/driver/cross_correlation.cpp:18:0:
/home/littlemonster/projects/rpi-workspace/lib/matrix-hal/matrix-
creator-hal/cpp/driver/cross_correlation.h:21:19: fatal error: 
fftw3.h: No such file or directory
#include <fftw3.h>
               ^
compilation terminated.
```

Because I am cross compiling and the library is present on the Raspberry Pi I don't link the library.

**Edit 2 to answer @Bartłomiej** :

The following lines are located in my `rpi-toolchain.cmake` file which is used when invoking cmake with the following : `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=rpi-toolchain.cmake`. When I try to specify the sysroot by setting `CMAKE_SYSROOT` the compiler is not even able to compile a test file.

```
# Define our host system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

SET(rpi-tools-dir ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/rpi-tools)

# Define the C cross compiler location
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER  ${rpi-tools-dir}/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)

# Define the CXX cross compiler location
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  ${rpi-tools-dir}/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

# Define the sysroot path for the RaspberryPi distribution in our tools folder
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${rpi-tools-dir}/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/)

# Only use binaries from the host and not from the toolchain sysroot
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search for libraries only in the target sysroot
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
# Search for the headers in the target and host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
```

Comment: Do a `make VERBOSE=1` to see gcc is called from the makefile. Paste the output of (of the few lines with error) in your question, not the comment section.

Comment: What does your compile command look like? Are you using "-lfftw3" in it?

Comment: Don't you miss sth like `set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ...)`? Can you show your CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: FYI facing the same issue with google/cpu_features. it seems that some linaro toolchain won't find `ld` when `--sysroot` is passed to gcc cross compiler (accroding to strace and qemu it seems to fallback to looking in /usr/lib/ld which is not suitable...). We try to use CMAKE_LINKER without success (cf https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-August/058271.html) Maybe we should try CMAKE_LINK_EECUTABLE instead https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake#L263

Comment: I mean CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake#L262

Comment: Thanks for the information. For my case, I think I'll end by building the fftw library myself for the project.